# Unity Addressables load everything in memory in Android build

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-management, addressables

Because my android game used too much device's RAM, i've decided to use Addressables system (with local assets, not downloadable). I tested it in Editor and it worked - memory consumption got much lower. However, when I built it for Android, there was no difference at all. Seems like Android build loads all my assets into memory though never asked to do so.

Memory usage in Editor:

[image: When lauched in Editor]

In Android (samescene, same objects in the scene):

[image: When lauched on Adnroid. The same scene]

Also, .apk file became even larger with addressables - it was 400 Mb, now it's 600.

Have no idea what can I try and do to resolve this.

Comment: First of all - it is not a good idea to compare any performance-related things in the editor and player, especially mobile one. Secondly - you can always check what concrete textures are loaded into the memory. Some assets can be loaded several times, compression can be overridden for the platform, etc.

Comment: Checking textures didn't give any clues - texture that I don't need at the moment doesn't load in Editor, but for some reason does in build.